# Up to which version will be old mysql supported?

Tags: php, mysql

we have to update our mySQL system because our installed verstion (5.2.6) is too old to install Composer. I need it to run with phpSpreadsheet.

The problem is that the php code was never updated to mysqli or something equivalent. It's still "old" mysql.

And at the moment we haven't enough manpower to update the code.

Up to which version runs mysql?

Security is not a reason because it's an internal database application only!

Thanks!
Markus

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Security is always a reason. Even (especially ?) if it's internal to an enterprise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use any version below MySql 5.0 .